# How to define authenticated helper in routes.rb to call or access application controller current_user method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to define authenticated root for the application. I am using  [omniauth-identity](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-identity) gem for the authentication and define current_user helper in application controller.

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user

def current_user=(user)
 session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

And in routes.rb
I want root based on condition

```
 root to: 'map#index', constraints: Constraints
 root to: 'pages#about'
```

And within Constraints.rb module defines matches? method

```
module Constraints
 def self.matches?(request)
   user = current_user(request)
   return true if user.present?
   false
 end
 def current_user(request)
   @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id]) if request.session[:user_id]
 end
end
```

And it works fine but the problem duplicate method current_user or we need to check session twice.

In routes we need to pass request object and available locally. so how we can call or pass controller current_user method with request object. Any suggestion so we can define in one place and access it.

It's something similar to devise gem
authenticated and unauthenticated routes helper.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding condition in routes, Simply direct it to application controller method and there use `redirect_to` to redirect accordingly.

```
class ApplicationController
  def index
    if current_user
      redirect_to "maps_path"
    else
      redirect_to "pages_path"
  end

  def current_user
    # your logic
  end
end
```

> in routes.rb

```
root to: /
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Hi, thanks Ravi for your answer, currently I do the same but don't want redirection of the request.
Just try to implement using conditional root.

Comment: Rails doesn't support conditions in routes. Constraints should be used with care. Constraints are usually used to match the params present in the routes.